# Getting BIOS serial number

Tags: winapi, bios

How do I get the BIOS serial number without using WMI API under Win32? I need a non WMI way cause WMI calls under Windows Guest account return as access denied.

Comment: Why do you need the BIOS serial number as a guest?

Comment: Sounds like getting anything like that from the BIOS would return as access denied when you're a guest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Guest account can change its account picture.  I recommend the fish.  That's about it, don't use Guest.